# Getting current location coordinates using Place picker google API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to save user form information with location field. For location I want to open google map on some button click and location to be selected when user click on location over map and post-filled location into form.

I am new to android and found place picker as related solution, So
I have used Place Picker Google API and  I am able to open google map, when I move arrow over preferred location and click on **Select this location (Appearing black color with now coordinates showing under that)**.

Confirmation box opens with 2 option :

1.) Change location
2.) Select **(Disabled mode)**

I want to select anonymous location and return to main activity.

Below is my code :

```
private TextView get_place;
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST    =   1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    get_place   =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    get_place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder   =   new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            Intent intent;
            try {
                intent  =   builder.build(getApplicationContext());
                startActivityForResult(intent,PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST );
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data ){
    if( requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Place place =   PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
            Double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            Double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
            String address = String.valueOf(latitude)+String.valueOf(longitude);
            get_place.setText(address);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know, If there is any other best solution.
Code reply will be much helpful or reference link.

Comment: any solution? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable places from your google developer api console